# Hiddenfield in a usercontrol, can not access it on clientside

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hidden field in a User Control. At run time I assign the hidden fields ClientId to an anchor tag like this:

```
aClickSort1.HRef = string.Format("javascript:SortImage({0},{1});", divArrowUp1.ClientID, hiddenSort1.ClientID);
```

The thing is that when I try to get the hidden fields ClientId in client side code, it is undefined.

How can access it on the client side code?

Ps. The HiddenField is in a usercontrol

Regards Örvar

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Visible="false"` to server side control, it will not be sent at all to the client.

Instead, set `style="display: none;"` or even better via CSS then it will be sent to the browser and still be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason is the **non-visible** container. If you have something like:

```
<asp:panel id="panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:hiddenfield id="hiddenfield1 runat="server" value="123"/>
</asp:panel>
```

You cannot access the stuff in `panel1` as things are not rendered for server side controls with `visible="false"` attribute.

You can set it into a `div` with `style="display:none;"` or just leave `hiddenfield` outside the `non-visible` container as it is not visible anyway.

Comment: @TheVillageldiot. Re: or just leave hiddenfield outside the non-visible container as it is not visible anyway. That is exactly how my hidden field is implemented.

Comment: are you writing the line in control's markup or in the page containing the control?

Comment: When i click the anchor a javascript error pops up and says that:'ctl00_mainWebPartManager_wp523183745_wp321661269_radPanelSettings_i0_hidde‌​nSort1' is undefined

Comment: function SortImage(divUpClientId, sort1) {} It says that sort1 is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to set hiddenSort1's ClientIdMode to Static.

Like this:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenSort1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

From javascript:

```
var hiddenSort1 = document.getElementById('hiddenSort1');
```

Comment: I tried to set ClientIdMode to static, it did not work. When i click the anchor a javascript error pops up and says that:'ctl00_mainWebPartManager_wp523183745_wp321661269_radPanelSettings_i0_hiddenSort1' is undefined

Comment: When you set ClientIDMode to static, it means that, in html page, element shuld have same id as it is in aspx page. So 'ctl00_mainWebPartManager_wp523183745_wp321661269_radPanelSettings_i0_hidde‌​nSort1' is not hidde‌​nSort1's id. Please check hidde‌​nSort1's id in html (In browser). What is hidde‌​nSort1 element id?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but isn´t the Id generated and if you have the hidden field in a user control it will get the Id of:

```
myUserControlName$myHiddenFieldId
```

?